# Mysql VB.NET: Hiding column from datagridview null exception error (column is not null)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is populated with the data I retrieved from the database (mysql)

When I try to hide the column or change the column header text, this exception was thrown:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

or

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

with this simple code:

```
gridjobs.Columns(0).Visible = False
gridjobs.Columns("JOB_NO").HeaderText = "JOB NO."
```

I can tell you that the datagrid is not null, it was working before but suddenly this error popped up. I tried searching the net but still no luck in fixing this error. Everything is working, except this. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't refer to a column by name unless you give it a name in the first place, which you will not have done.  The `ColumnName` of your `DataColumn` does not automatically get assigned to the `Name` of a `DataGridViewColumn` when you bind.

Comment: I named it, I got: Argument out of range exception

Comment: Why did you bother naming it?  You have two lines of code there.  One uses a ordinal.  Why wouldn't you do the same in both cases?  That said, if you get that exception then you aren't doing it right.

Comment: did you check that everytime you execute your code there are column in your datagrid? maybe there's a part in your code that can conflict in later part in your code thats why it returns an error

Comment: I did, I change the "JOB_NO" to 1, I got the error: Index was out of range. Is there something with the grid properties perhaps? I don't know. As I said, it was working before.. It just popped up suddenly when I added another grid in the form. Is that it? but when I removed it, the error is still there? I've been doing random things to make the code work, but none so far.

Comment: I'll check the thing that you said that conflicts. Maybe you're true

Comment: I feel stupid, I think I'm gonna redo the whole system. This is a bummer. Sigh

Answer (score 0):

based on google

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exactly what it says, you are trying to use a null object as if it was a properly referenced object. ... Most of the time, when you try to assing value into object, and if the value is null, then this kind of exception occur.

This one is common sense here is your code.

`gridjobs.Columns(0).Visible = False
gridjobs.Columns("JOB_NO").HeaderText = "JOB NO."`

the first column is `Visible = False` then you assigned a header text? How can I assign a value in an Object that Invisible?

Just a wild guess.

and also why do u need to assign a header that will be `visible = false` also? anyway try this

`gridjobs.Columns(0).Visible = False
gridjobs.Columns(0).HeaderText = "JOB NO."`